# How to change image button on click then get back

Tags: javascript, html, image, button

I have an image button and I would like to do that if I click to the img button it is changed, then if I click again to the button it change back to the default image.

I have this script but it doesnt change back. Anybody can help me?

```
<script>
  function VOR2(img) 
  {
    if(img.src.match(/blank/))
    {
      img.src = "VOR.gif";
    }
    else
    {
      img.src = "VOR2.gif";
    }
  }
</script>    
<img src="VOR.gif" id="VOR2" onclick=VOR2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that your code is currently not working is because `img.src.match(/blank/)` looks if the image source has the text "blank" (the forward slashes make it a [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)). However neither images you have provided include the text "blank", so it simply does nothing, and isn't the best use case anyways.

The best practice for this would be toggling a class with `classList` to your image to help identify which "state" it is in, such as the below:

```
<script>
function VOR2(img) {
  isChanged = img.classList.contains('changed-image');
  img.src = isChanged ? 'VOR.gif' : 'VOR2.gif';
  img.classList.toggle('changed-image');
}
</script>    
<img src="VOR.gif" id="VOR2" onclick=VOR2>
```

I would also suggest moving the script into a different file.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way :

JS :

```
function VOR2(img) {
  if (img.src == "VOR2.gif") {
    img.src = "VOR.gif";
  } else {
    img.src = "VOR2.gif";
  }

  console.log(img.src);
}
```

HTML :

```
<img src="VOR.gif" id="VOR2" onclick="VOR2(this)" />
```